# Deploy maven project to custom/own repository (override)

Tags: java, maven

I want to build and deploy a project to my own repository - how can I specify target repository for `deploy` goal? I know that I can use `deploy:deploy-file` but this only applies for single file. I would like to build complete project (with multiple modules).

Context: there is a project I use as dependency, but I use snapshot artifacts from `master` branches and original owner doesn't build/provide snapshot dependencies. I could fork the project, specify `distributionManagement` with repository coordination, but that would be way too complex. Unfortunately "local repository" would be problematic as it's to be built in CI.

Comment: Define the distributionManagement... in your own project... too complex? ...

Comment: @zforgo it seems like what I'm looking for - thanks!

Comment: @khmarbaise have you read second part of the question? "too complex"? It's NOT my project, I can't add the section unless I fork it, and doing a fork just to add `distributionManagement` section seems silly at the very least...

Comment: I've read that... but if you use it and it's not your project... you have to request a change for that or you have to fork it...  and is not published via a repository manager ? And why to your "own repository"???  (Is that a corporate environment?)

Comment: Deploying nightly is not usually common (and for good reasons) so demanding project would do so doesn't seem right. I'm doing certain extensions and custom packaging of the build (as suggested by the projects maintainers!) and I require features/changes that are already in the master (thus x.y.z-SNAPSHOT). The only way to achieve that is either build upstream project before each CI build of our project (based on upstream) or build it once, deployed the SNAPSHOTS that we need (and it's easier to do to our repository). Is it somewhat clearer? When upstream publishes stable we will switch.